# How can I package a project with a SQLite database?

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans

I made a desktop project in Netbeans 17, which is a sales system, which has a portable SQLite database. Before packaging the project I make the tests and everything works correctly making connection to the database and the queries that I want, but the problem arises when after cleaning and building the project, I package it in JAR, I run the JAR to see if everything is still working correctly and I have the problem that no longer makes the connection to the database. I don't know why and how can I solve this problem, any suggestions? I would appreciate it very much.

I have been investigating possible solutions and one of them is that I should configure my project so that when I am packaging in JAR I also include the file where I have the database. But the steps that I get is not the same that I get in the Netbeans 17 that I have, so I can not find the way to include it, I do not know if it is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

[JAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) files are meant to be unchanging, read-only. The "ar" stands for “archive”.

You will write your database file somewhere *outside* the JAR. Every computer platform has specific places where an application should write its supporting files.

You can bundle a database within your JAR to be used as a template. At runtime, you would copy that database to a location outside the JAR. After that, let the database engine open the copied database.

Or, alternatively, you could create a new fresh empty database outside the JAR. Then use a [database migration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration) tool such as [*Flyway*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyway_(software)) or [*Liquibase*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquibase) to run a series of SQL scripts. Those scripts would create the needed tables, columns, indexes, etc. And those scripts could create any essential data in those tables, as expected by your app. (I don't know if those tools support SQLite or not. They support many other database engines.)

---

Be aware that SQLite is native software. When you bundle a SQLite engine with your app, that can only work on one specific OS & chip architecture.

If you want a run-anywhere database engine, you have a few pure Java databases to choose from. These include H2, HSQLDB (HyperSQL), and Derby. (I would recommend [H2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(database)).)